# Android displays '?" question mark when receiving response from Restful web service

Tags: php, android, mysql

Android displays `?` question mark when receiving response from Restful web service.

I have `armscii8_bin` type text in MYSQL database. I am trying to get that data from my Android application. When I receive a response, those are question marks (?????)

Although when typed in Android Studio that text is being displayed properly. In the app the text is also displayed properly. I am working with Armenian text.

Maybe someone came across with similar problem with other languages. I have changed the connection property from `UTF-8` to `armscii8_bin` but it has not solved the problem.

```
setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", armscii8_bin);
```

Thank you

Comment: `UTF-8` supports thousands of different glyphs. You should try setting everything to `UTF-8` and (at least in the short term), cast the `armscii8_bin` text to `UTF-8` to see if that helps.

Comment: In the beginning it was UTF-8 because I have always worked with English text, but it has not worked. I hoped changing it to the one I have in database will solve the problem, but it didn't. The database also would save question marks, before I changed it to armscii8_bin. Thanks

Comment: You need to have both the database and the app the same, but UTF-8 is the way to go for both. In your `SELECT` use `CONVERT(col_name_here) USING utf8`. You'll also need to make sure that the font you're using to display has the appropriate glyphs to display.

Comment: The following two are SQl queries that I perform on server side.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tales (author, title, content, favor, other, image) VALUES ('$author', '$title', '$content', '$favor', '$other', '$image')") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tales WHERE title = '$title'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Kevin Nagurski could you please change them according to your recommendation on using CONVERT with them. I have already changed all the columns to use utf8_bin Collation, but still no success. I still receive question marks.

Comment: If you've changed the collation, you don't need the `CONVERT` statement. Check to make sure you're using a font that supports your characters. The big name fonts like Arial and Helvetica usually have the best support.

Comment: Yes Kevin, I am using regular font. The text is displayed properly both in the development environment and in all the parts of the android app. The problem occurs when parsing json response and json contains question marks as values.